# Prioritize application installed locally over same application in app-v

Tags: windows-10

We currently have an application which has been deployed to multiple users over app-v. We also have a need to install and test the a newer version of the same application locally.

When we start the locally installed application, we see in procmon that everything starts off as expected. At some point it starts to call other executables, but for an unknown reason it starts calling the executables from the app-v package.

Is there a way to either remove the app-v package or to always prioritize the locally installed application?

Comment: You could consider running the test app in a virtual machine such as Hyper-V, Oracle VirtualBox or VMWare. That said, app-v packages can be shielded off from eachother. So if a new app-v is created for that newer version you should not have any problems with it either.

Comment: We have considered that, but creating a new app-v package for an application that might require additional configuration and changes adds an overhead we were hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Is this App-v 5.1?

If so this is the nature of App-v being more integrated than the older softgrid 4.6 versions.

You could unpublish the package while running your local test app?

Powershell

```
Unpublish-AppvClientPackage -Name "APPNAME*
```

If it is still accessing files in the packgage you may need to just remove it from the machine

Powershell

```
Remove-AppvClientPackage -name "Appname"
```

This will clear out the app cache so be warned if there is/was any user preferences changed after time of sequencing.

Afterwards resyncing the publishing server will bring you back to where u were.

Powershell

```
Get-AppvPublishingServer | Sync-AppvPublishingServer
```